# enp5s0 : Reset Adapter

Tags: networking, kernel

I have an error with Ubuntu 18,
suddenly my server network hangs, and must be restarted, and then I can return.
Can help me  with this problem?

[image]

```
[363794.283022] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Reset adapter
[364565.076382] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Reset adapter
[366066.216858] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Reset adapter
[366088.232214] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Reset adapter
[366105.127736] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Reset adapter
```

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. Rather, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: please help me,